# pyhon min function with predicate

Tags: python, for-loop, distance, min

Say we have an nxk matrix with boolean values representing the locations of items. Your location is known and we want to find the item closest to us.

I want to write it in one sentence using python's min function. (the long implementation is known)

I'm expecting to write something like the following:

```
min_dist = min(distance(my_location, (x,y)) for x,y in
/*range(n),range(k) such that item_matrix[x][y] == True*/ )
```

Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `for` loops and an `if` condition (Line breaks optional, just for better readability):

```
min_dist = min(distance(my_location, (x,y))
               for x in range(n)
               for y in range(k)
               if item_matrix[x][y])
```

Or using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
min_dist = min(distance(my_location, (x,y))
               for (x, y) in product(range(n), range(k))
               if item_matrix[x][y])
```

The `== True` part is only needed if `item_matrix` can contain other "truthy" values besides `True`, such as numbers, strings, etc., but not if only `True` and `False`.